# Get all text by page

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Jumping in the deep end doing some scripting for Indesign. I want to grab all the text by each page (in order).

I've written a function to do this via stories. However, I want to sort the stories so they are on a page  by page basis.

Using `for (var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.pages.length; i++)` isn't useful in this case. I'm not sure how the stories ID relates to page placement.

This is what I've got

```
function get_all_stories()
{
    var str = "";
    var CR = "\r\n"; // carriage return

    for(var i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.stories.length; i++)
    {
        var myStory = app.activeDocument.stories.item(i);

        // add contents to string
        str += myStory.contents + CR + CR;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all characters and check what the page belongs `parentTextFrame` of the character. If next character belongs the same page as previous one you concatenate it in one string. As soon page is changed you make a next string. Etc. This way you can get the array of strings-pages for one given story:

```
var texts = [];
var text_on_page = "";
var story = app.activeDocument.stories[0];
var chars = story.texts[0].characters.everyItem().getElements();

var current_page = chars[0].parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
var prev_page = current_page;

for (var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
    var ch = chars[i];
    current_page = ch.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
    if (current_page == prev_page) { 
        text_on_page += ch.contents;
    }
    else {
        prev_page = current_page;
        texts.push(text_on_page);
        text_on_page = ch.contents;
    }
}

texts.push(text_on_page); // text from last page

// print report
var report = ""
for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
    report += "\nPage " + (i+1) + " contains: '" + texts[i] + "'\n";
}
alert(report);
```

[image]

But it will be more complicated if you have several stories. Perhaps you will need to get page splitten texts form each story and then figure out how to concatenate texts from different stories if they share the same page.